# jCarouselLite Setting number of visible items dynamically

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I'm attempting to use jQuery jCarouselLite in my project, but there does not seem to be a way to change the "visible" option dynamically based on screen size.  Is it possible to change the original configuration parameters and see the changes in the UI immediately?

Comment: please show some code by which get proper idea of your problem

Comment: My problem is that I cant figure out how to change the values of the original configuration, and then see the changes in the UI thereafter.  I have no code worth showing, everything I've tried has been completely on a whim after looking at source code and googling, but to no avail.

Comment: see in plugin js file defaults in this you can set your desired changes

Comment: Could you provide some additional information?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry maybe this was unclear... but I'm looking to do this dynamically based on a screen-resize.  Like, is there a way to access the jQueryLite object, set a new number of visible items, then refresh the carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here is how you'd do it :

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/upTvn/1/)

**Try resizing the RESULT window in the fiddle to see it in effect**

JS:

```
    $(function() {
    $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        visible: 5
    });
});

$(window).trigger('resize');

$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 300 && $(window).width() < 400){
        $('.next, .prev').unbind('click');
        $('.anyClass').jCarouselLite({
            visible: 3.5,
            btnNext: ".next",
            btnPrev: ".prev"
        });
    }
    else if($(window).width() > 400 && $(window).width() < 500){
        $('.next, .prev').unbind('click');
        $('.anyClass').jCarouselLite({
            visible: 4.5,
            btnNext: ".next",
            btnPrev: ".prev"
        });
    }
    else if($(window).width() >= 500){
        $('.next, .prev').unbind('click');
        $('.anyClass').jCarouselLite({
            visible: 5,
            btnNext: ".next",
            btnPrev: ".prev"
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="prev"><<</button>
<button class="next">>></button>

<div class="anyClass">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is so close.  Notice, if you move the carousel to the right a few times, then resize it, then hit right again, it goes through like 3 slides, I think back to slide 1.

Comment: Cool..got your problem. Fixed it and updated the fiddle. Bascially I have to update the click handlers for the buttons as well. Hence, I first unbind the associated clicks and then bind them again using the jCarouselLite plugin